# SwiftUI show/hide title issues with NavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, swiftui

I have the following code construct which gives me a lot of trouble:

```
//Main View
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack(alignment: .center){
                CarouselBuilder()
                ProfileInvoke().navigationBarTitle("").navigationBarHidden(true)
            }
        }
    }
}

//Carousel filled with Cards from a DB 
...code irrelevant for my problem

//Profile Invoke -> Invokes a slide out menu called Menu that has NavigationLinks in it
struct Menu: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack(alignment: .center){
                    MenuButton(buttonText: "Settings", buttonCallView: AnyView(SettingsView() ))
                    MenuButton(buttonText: "My Favourites", buttonCallView: AnyView(MyFavouritesView()))
                    MenuButton(buttonText: "Sign Out", buttonCallView: AnyView(SignOutView()))
            }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width/1.2,alignment: .top)
        }
    }
}

//MenuButtons are basic NavigationLinks linking to certain Views given as argument when calling them
```

I now do wrap the `ZStack` in the Main View in a NavigationView which I need to to in order for the `NavigationLinks` to work. I also have to do this on this "top" level as I need the new View that will be invoked by the links in the slide out menu to take the entire screen and not only the width the slide out view is being displayed.

My issue is now that I certainly do not want the navigation bar to take up space in the main view. For this I set the hidden attribute for it to true. This tho, carries through the entire app and also disables the navigation view in the subviews linked to by the buttons in the menu. Which gives me no way of going back.

My question would be: 
1) Is there a more elegant way of doing all of this?
2) How can I re-invoke the navigation bar in sub views? (Setting the hidden navigation bar  attribute on them back to false did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a possible approach to hide navigation bar in root view and show in child subviews. The only needed modifications is in root view.

Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

Here is a root only, child sub-views are regular and do not require special code for this case. See important notes inline.

```
struct RootNavigationView: View {
    @State private var hideBar = true // << track hide state, and default
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("I'm ROOT")
                Divider()
                NavigationLink("Goto Child", destination: NextChildView(index: 1))
                 .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                    self.hideBar = false     // << show, here to be smooth !!
                 })
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(hideBar)
        //    .navigationBarTitle("Back to Root") // << optional 
            .onAppear {
                self.hideBar = true  // << hide on back
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add some view to the top of `RootNavigationView`, you will see that it's offset by the size of navigation bar, even though the navigation bar is not visible. This offset will go away only if the `navigationBarTitle` is used on the root. But in this case, you'll see an ugly jump of the view at the top of the root when navigating to the child view...

Comment: I've experienced the same. Had to rethink my design to do something else so I could get rid of that...