# How to hide navigation bar only in first view when using SwiftUI and UIKit views

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a main view that I'm using swiftUI for and I want to hide the navbar for. I've used

```
.navigationBarTitle(Text("Home"), displayMode: .inline)
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

to hide the navbar on this main page. My problem is that I use a navigation link to go to a UIKit view that I've created and I can't get the navbar to show up on this page no matter what I do. I've tried setting `navigationBarHidden(false)` under the navLink and that doesn't work, nor does

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }
```

in my UIKit view. I need to be able to have the back button displayed at the top for subsequent pages. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If your UIKit wrapped into UIViewRepresentable as I hope, then the solution from [SwiftUI show/hide title issues with NavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60996978/12299030) should be helpful

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks!