# SwiftUI Show navigation bar title on the back button but not in the previous View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have two views, one leads to the other. I want that the second view uses the title of the first view for the back button, which should then be: "<View1".
I don't want to show the title in the first view.

Problem: I can't hide navigation bar because it will also hide a *custom button* which is within it. Setting `.navigationTitle("")` hides the title in the first view, but also hides it from the back button in the second view.

What I have now:

[image]
[image]

What I would like to have:

[image]
[image]

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isLinkActive = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
            NavigationLink("go to the second view", destination: SecondView(), isActive: $isLinkActive).navigationTitle("View1")
                .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                    ()
                }, label: {
                    Text("custom button")
                }))
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        
    }
    
    private func btnPressed() {
        isLinkActive = true
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.blue
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60996978/12299030?

Comment: @Asperi but this hides the navigation bar so my custom button (which is a navigationBarItem) will not be visible then ? I need to show this custom button

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom back button for destination view as well,and you shouldn’t set navigation title for `navigationLink`, that’s why you are not able to hide ***“View1”*** correctly.

Check below code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {
    @State var isLinkActive = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink("go to the second view", destination: SecondView()
                                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                                .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                                    isLinkActive = false
                                }, label: {
                                    HStack{
                                        Image(systemName: "backward.frame.fill")
                                        Text("View1")
                                    }
                                })) ,
                               isActive: $isLinkActive)
                
            }.navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
                ()
            }, label: {
                Text("custom button")
            }))
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        
        
    }
    
    private func btnPressed() {
        isLinkActive = true
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Color.blue
    }
}
```

You can try and make `navigationBar` code as reusable component, because you might need to do this at multiple places.

**Output-:**

[image]
[image]

Comment: I like this approach but unfortunately it does not result in having the system icon so it will not be consistent with the rest of my app. I would probably have to search for the correct asset and the right font for the text which already makes it more like a workaround than the actual solution

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by using two modifiers on my main view. Similar to your case, I didn't want a title on the first view, but I wanted the back button on the pushed view to read `< Home`, not `< Back`.

```
.navigationTitle("Home")
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        Text("")
    }
}
```